# Copy From One Table To Another Specific Cols And Variables

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi,**
I Want to copy from one table to another with the specific cols.
In addition i want to add to the query an external variable. for example in one table i have col1,col2,col3 and in the second table i have the same cols ( col1,col2,col2 ) 

 but now i want to insert to the col4 a variable. it will be like : insert into col1,col2,col3,**col4** select (col1,col2,col3,$VARIABLE)

```
$copy_cols= 'INSERT INTO A (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,$VAR FROM B WHERE Descriptiontable="AAA"';
 mysql_cols($copy_query);
```

the col4 is not can be found in table B , so i want to insert to this col some variable.. for example : the variable can be a constant number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$copy_cols = 'INSERT INTO A (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4) 
              SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3,'FOO' AS COL4 
              FROM B WHERE Descriptiontable="AAA"';
mysql_cols($copy_query);
```

Comment: If i want to add a if not exist where i need to write it?